# Qiskit installation failing: VC++ 2017 not found

Tags: qiskit, programming

I tried to follow the web instructions to load Qiskit, including VC++ 2017 Redistributable, but I get many errors upon installation.  The gist seems to be that VC++ 2017 wasn't found.  Some results coped below - any suggestions?

```
=========================================================
.
.
.
  Building wheel for qiskit-aer (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
.
.
.
.
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
.
.
.
.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for qiskit-aer
  Running setup.py clean for qiskit-aer
  Building wheel for qiskit-terra (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
.
.
.
.
    scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.

Building windows wheels for Python 3.8 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.
Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":

  https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/
```

Comment: Hi @Dave! Could you provide more details, like the link of the webpage you're following, OS, and full log? Thanks!

Comment: Hi C.!  Thanks for your reply.  I was following the directions at https://qiskit.org/documentation/install.html,  I am using Windows10.  I'd like to attach my log but can't see how to do that; if you give me an email, I'll send it.

Comment: Is there any way to send or post a full log of the problem (74000 characters)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I'd recommend posting the log to pastebin then sharing the link. What step in installation does it fail?

Comment: thanks for the reply!  I have put the log at https://pastebin.com/ys0c3DY3,  the first error reads,   Building wheel for qiskit-aer (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\DaveR\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\Env2_for_QISkit\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\DaveR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1oanpuze\\qiskit-

Comment: did you install the C++ Redistributable? It was in the installation guide

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue.
Installed VC++ Redistributable and Visual studio but does not work...

Comment: I installed VC_redist.x64 as recommended.

Comment: Did you install the c++ tools components?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using Python 3.8. Qiskit only works with Python 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7 - [see here for details](https://pypi.org/project/qiskit/)

In most cases using Python 3.7 is enough, but if you get another error: `TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType` you can try the below part.

After downgrading to Python 3.7.3 and pip 19.1.1 it still gave an error - it could not resolve a path to VC++ 2017 Redistributable for `fastdtw`.

For me it worked to hack it like this:

1. Find where you have instaleed `vcruntime140.dll`. I found a copy in `%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\envs\<<environment_name>>\vcruntime140.dll`
2. Open the file `%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\envs\<<environment_name>>\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py`
3. Edit the function `def VCRuntimeRedist(self)` to return the path to `vcruntime140.dll` (don't forget to escape the `\`s)
4. run `pip install qiskit`

Comment: That first part was important, I replaced Python 3.8 with Python 3.7 within Anaconda Navigator, ran reran the VC++ 2017 Redistributable, then the new install went smoothly.  Didn't seem to be a need for the second hack - thanks!

Comment: @DaveRDen - approve Sorin's answer!

Answer (score -1):

Do install Microsoft Visual C++ . So tat the error can be satisfied. And also do `pip install wheel`.